# Need help differentiating this equations

Tags: derivatives

I would like to know how differentiate this equation it should be fairly simple but its been a long night and I cant seem to figure it out.

$r =\frac{f}{R . \hat z} R$

with respect to time.

- f is some constant (focal length)
- R is a position vector
- $R . \hat z $ is inner product

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{f}{R.z\hat R}$? You get this as `$\frac{f}{R.z\hat R}$`.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more readable.

Comment: I'm guessing it should be $R (\hat z \cdot R)$.

Comment: sorry about that, it has now been correctly formatted

Comment: Does $\hat{z}$ depends on time?

Comment: $\hat z $ is actually just a unit vector in a specific direction (z-axis), R is a position vector

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the direction of $\hat z$ does not change with time,
$$
\begin{align}
\dot r &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{fR}{\langle R, \hat z\rangle}\right)\\
& = \frac{f}{\langle R, \hat z\rangle^2}\left[\langle R, \hat z\rangle \dot R- R\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\langle R, \hat z\rangle\right)\right]\\
& = \frac{f}{\langle R, \hat z\rangle^2}\left[\langle R, \hat z\rangle \dot R- \langle \dot R, \hat z\rangle R\right]
\end{align}
$$